# fetch numeric value from string

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

from this file, I need all the numeric values:

```
textextone^1234)
tttexttwO^414)
teeetextthrEe^153)
randomdatattextFoR^153)
```

I have tried:

```
grep "(?<='[a-zA-Z]'\^)[^\)]*" file
```

thanx a lot guys !

Comment: the begining of 'grep search' should not start by ^ as in the actual file it would make a confusion with other strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using sed**

```
sed  's/[^0-9]//g' filename
```

**Using grep**

```
grep -o "[0-9]*" filename
```

Comment: very interesting; would it be possible to include one or two letter and '^' otherwise, it will confuse with other strings in the actual file. Following your solution, I have tried in vain:

Comment: sed -n 's/[^a-zA-Z]\^[0-9]//pg' test.dump

Comment: As per your expression until a-z found do something, it occurs in first position so it won't match as per you required. Alternative you can use `sed  -r 's/[a-zA-Z]+\^([0-9]*).*/\1/g' filename`

Comment: this one is pretty cool Kalanidhi; can you do it with grep as well?

Comment: grep cannot work like a `sed` , it match the specify pattern with some option.

Comment: I finally found it with grep: `grep -oP "(?<=[a-zA-Z]\^[0-9])[^)]*" `

Answer (score 0):

Using sed you can do:

```
sed 's/[^[:digit:]]\{1,\}//g' file
1234
414
153
153
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl One-Liner

Use this:

```
perl -ne 'while(m/\d+/g){print "$&\n";}' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `-o` of `grep`:

```
egrep -o '[[:digit:]]+' file
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' file
grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' file
egrep -o '[0-9]+' file
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file
grep -o '[0-9]\+' file
```

Output:

```
1234
414
153
153
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F^ '{print $2+0}' file
1234
414
153
153
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tr -d -c '[:digit:]\n' < file
1234
414
153
153
```